# Connecting flush mount split service panels

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

I have split service (I think) - 2 panels with separate 200A switches. The panels are flush mount. I want to install a Sense monitor which requires linking between these two. What's the best way to connect these?

[image: picture of left panel opened up]

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by linking the panels? Note when you hear the term 240 split this is to define North American power. It is a single phase that is transformed down to 240v with a center tap in the middle that is grounded so from the center tap to each end is 120v but end to end is 240. Are you thinking conduit or a cable for CT’s ? Not actually connecting the 2 panels right?

Comment: @Ed this looks to me like classic 400A service with two 200A main panels.  OP is asking an XY question, and their X is "how do I create pass-throughs between the panels?" Sounds to me like the X is a question about conduit, and the Y is "how do I make  home energy monitors made for one main work on 400A/dual 200 service?"

Comment: Has the OP looked into Sense Flex?   Looks tailor made for his application as it supports a 400 amp service.

Comment: @harper I wanted to make sure as I have been asked to parallel panels in the past.

Comment: Yes, I mean how do I physically connect them, not electrically. I do have the extra sensors mentioned on the flex page. I am looking to accomplish this: https://sense.com/guides/400a/

Answer (score 4):

Here's what I ended up doing. I knocked out two 1/2" knockouts in the bottom of each panel and fed the Sense Flex cable (this is low voltage) through those with some simple plastic bushings. I drilled a hole through the stud below the panels which the cable fit through. I had to make a big enough hole below the panels to drill the hole but was able to get the cable up without having to make the drywall hole super big. In hind sight, I would have just made a bigger hole so it was easier to drill and feed the cable since the patch work is about the same and being able to drill the patch into the stud is easier than relying on the paper.

Comment: I'd probably use a Raco Insider or similar retrofit NM clamp to strain relief the LV cable as it exits the panel (unless that's the thing you mean by "plastic bushing", that is)